# How to copy a script element to the parent from inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which needs to copy a script to the parent and execute a function in the parent:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script id="myscript">
  function foo() { alert('foo'); }
  </script>

  <script>
  (function () {
    var script = document.getElementById('myscript');
    parent.document.head.appendChild(script);

    // call function in parent 
    parent.foo();
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get undefined is not a function. Why is that function not defined in the parent?

Comment: isn't what you are trying to do considered xss? If you own both pages, perhaps you can use your server as a middle man and use ajax on both pages to pass the scripts.

Comment: unfortunately ajax is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that you will be subject to cross-origin security and other inter-frame restrictions, which shouldn't be an issue if you host both frames from the same domain, but will block this pretty effectively otherwise.

Getting an element from the child frame and appending it to the parent probably won't work, and is definitely overly complex. I would suggest creating a new script element on the parent and simply copying the content. Something like:

```
(function () {
    var pdoc = parent.document;
    var dest = pdoc.head;
    var text = document.getElementById("myscript").textContent;

    var pscr = pdoc.createElement("script");
    pscr.textContent = text;
    dest.appendChild(pscr);

    parent.foo();
})();
```

This is fairly difficult to make a good example for, as JSFiddle and the like serve their frames from different origins, so I haven't tested it thoroughly. Getting the script content this way definitely works, and creating the element certainly should. The closest I could come while testing was to rename the function and use the current frame:

```js
(function() {
  var pdoc = self.document;
  var dest = pdoc.head;
  var text = document.getElementById("myscript").textContent.replace("foo", "bar");

  var pscr = pdoc.createElement("script");
  pscr.textContent = text;
  dest.appendChild(pscr);

  self.bar();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want this to be a more portable solution, you may also look into using the `onMessage` handler in the script and firing a message from the child (message-passing is somewhat more complex, but often more maintainable, than inter-frame calls).

Comment: Thank you for your most excellent answer. Any ideas why copying the script element does not work?

Comment: I don't know for sure that it doesn't, but elements are tied into the DOM in a number of ways. There's no reasonable way to copy all of the possible bindings and dependencies, but all your really need (especially in this case) is the content of the node, so creating a new one is probably a much better idea.